# Making a "concave-up" polynomial function that passes through three points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need a polynomial function (of minimal degree) that is guaranteed to pass through the points $(0,1)$, $(c,0)$, and $(1,1)$ where $c$ is guaranteed to be on the interval $(0..1)$, such that on the interval $(0..1)$, the function is never negative on the interval, and whose second derivative never falls below zero over the interval.

Edit:

I can fairly easily find a rational function that fits the criteria...
$${\frac { \left( c-x \right) ^{2}}{2\,c{x}^{2}+{c}^{2}-4\,cx-{x}^{2}+2
\,x}}$$
But I don't know if I can find a polynomial function that imitates this behavior on the same interval.

It could be approximated with a taylor series expansion of the above rational function, but it seems that any fixed degree expansion gets increasingly imprecise for this function as c gets nearer to either 0 or to 1 and often even violates the constraints of the original problem.

This makes me wonder if a fixed degree polynomial solution is even possible... but I don't know how to prove that it impossible, so I can't be sure that it is.

Comment: Use a parabola.

Comment: A parabola doesn't work... for reasons I realized after I posted.  I have amended the question

Comment: Silently modifying the problem statement after the fact is bad practice.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be silent about it.  If I were, I would not have said I amended the question

Comment: @Mark: right, but the reader can't guess what was the initial question.

Comment: It was not my intention to be rude or suggest the comment was unhelpful.  I was only trying to explain why that answer would not work for me

Answer (score 4):

The Lagrangian interpolation polynomial by these points is

$$y(x)=\frac{(x-c)(x-1)}{(0-c)(0-1)}+\frac{(x-0)(x-c)}{(1-0)(1-c)}.$$

It turns out that the second derivative is the constant

$$2\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1{1-c}\right),$$ which is positive.

---

**Updated question**:

If the function must be positive, a parabola can't do in general, and at least a fourth degree polynomial is required.

$$a(x-c)^4+b(x-c)^2$$ where you determine $a,b$ from the given conditions will probably do.

Comment: I am so truly sorry for marking your answer as correct already... I regret I had to undo it.  your answer seems perfectly reasonable and seemed so obvious when I read it, that I felt foolish for even asking the question and prematurely marked your answer as right. when I actually got around to plotting the function, however, I noticed that there was a local maximum on the interval 0..1 when c was not equal to 1/2, which means that the second derivative becomes 0 on the interval.   Thank you, however.

Comment: @Mark: right. I forgot to say (and I didn't check) that $a,b$ must both be positive. I may be that they are never.

Comment: They may both be positive for some values of c but for the first one I tried, c=1/3, a worked out to be negative.